# Google Sheets, populate with multiple arrays

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-finance

I am using GOOGLEFINANCE() function to pull historical data from a ticker, all works good and I get an array with a fixed number a columns and a dynamic number of rows.
Now I want to create a database and pull data from multiple tickers (which I store in column A, and I add manually). The database has to expand automatically based on which tickers I add as new rows.

I have made the example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nDkIvVIWmibB2jiLyJCeHPNxdA11A1AMoavI-ICtSdE/edit?usp=sharing

What I tried is to populate the initial google finance formula every 6 column and pull the data.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MOD(COLUMN(A1:Z1) - COLUMN(A1) + 1, 6) = 1, GOOGLEFINANCE(A1:A, "all", "02.01.2023", "20.12.2023", "weekly"), ""))
```

That does not work.
But maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(torow(,1),tocol(A:A,1),lambda(a,c,hstack(a,googlefinance(c, "all", "02.01.2023", "20.12.2023", "weekly"))))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm. If you would have some time to explain a bit the thought process it would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can look into [reduce/lambda](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLv9Pf9aNgemvXxLZfObnb3cvcG6gerfOB) function(s), its processing the codes in column_A one at a time (we have 2 in the test scenario); Cell_A1 value is picked first→your google finance function is applied and processed→Cell_A2 value is picked next & processed→output is stacked horizontally(*hstack*) aside the first output and so on...